# Importing Rpy with python 2.6, R2.14 and Win 7x64 error

Tags: python, rpy2, rpython

I am trying to import rpy into python.  I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in module
    import rpy
  File "E:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy.py", line 58, in module
    RVERSION = rpy_tools.get_R_VERSION(RHOME)
  File "E:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy_tools.py", line 103, in get_R_VERSION
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't obtain version number from output\n"
RuntimeError: Couldn't obtain version number from output
of `R --version'.
```

I looked on the forums and found the following thread with the same issue.  Followed what someone recommend there and I still get the same error.  I have Rpy 1.0.3, Python 2.6, R2.14 and Windows 7 x64.  I also have numpy 1.6.1 and pywin32 build 216 per recommended by the rpy site for windows installs.

[Importing rpy module into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890706/importing-rpy-module-into-python)

R is in the path and the same error still occurs.

Added the path to the x64 R.exe. Also went in like the above post and added the extra +'s.  Still runs in Command line but now getting a new error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>          import rpy
>         File "E:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\rpy.py", line 101, in 
>          raise RuntimeError("Unable to locate R.dll within %s" % RHOME)
>        RuntimeError: Unable to locate R.dll within C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0

Going to search Stack for other errors witl the R.dll.  Seems there are 2 R.dll's too. one in i386 and one in x64.

Found in rpy.py

if sys.platform=='win32':
    import win32api
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(RHOME,'bin')

So I added in after 'bin' a 'i386','x64','R.dll'. Still the same error even after I tell it where to look.  Found some stuff on editing the "rinterface/**init**.py" but I can't find this file.  Granted that was for rpy2 that seems to be running into the same problem.

Well not sure what I changed but now I am getting the following

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import rpy
>     File "E:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy.py", line 106, in 
>       win32api.LoadLibrary( Rlib )
>   error: (126, 'LoadLibrary', 'The specified module could not be found.')

Tried it in x64 mode. Got an error that loadlibrary cant work in x64 as it is a win32 module.  Went back to i386 and thus got an error saying rpy wont work with R2.14.0. Going to try a old version of R.

Upon further review I am an idiot.  I downloaded rpy2 made the same following changes and it works like a charm.

Comment: What happens when you go to the command line and type `R --version`?

Comment: @Steven, that was asked on the other question.  I have a feeling R isn't in the PATH.  (Most Windows programs don't add themselves.)

Comment: @Steven, if i run it in a windows command line it comes up with it is not a internal or external command.  When I type that within R it comes up with 'R' not found.  Same within Python command line.  I have R 2.14.  I don't know if it would matter but I have R installed on my C and python installed on my E.  Looking into the rpy code though it searches through the reg to find where R is located to then find the version of R that is on the computer.

Comment: With the help of a friend he led me to http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

I added the R path and now in a command prompt I type R and it runs R. I type R --version and I get  R Version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31) Platform i386-pc-migw32/i386 (32-bit).  Still get the same error when importing rpy though.

Comment: Try to find the ```raise RuntimeError("Couldn't obtain version number``` line in the code, and just before it you should have access to "the output".  Try printing that output to the screen.  If that doesn't work: back-track.